# Assignment with both fillna() and loc() apparently not working

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, supervised-learning, fillna

I've searched for answer around, but I cannot find them.

My goal: **I'm trying to fill some missing values in a DataFrame**, using supervised learning to decide how to fill it.

My code looks like this: **NOTE - THIS FIRST PART IS NOT IMPORTANT, IT IS JUST TO GIVE CONTEXT**

```
train_df = df[df['my_column'].notna()]     #I need to train the model without using the missing data
train_x = train_df[['lat','long']]         #Lat e Long are the inputs
train_y = train_df[['my_column']]          #My_column is the output
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(2)
clf.fit(train_x,train_y)                   #clf is the classifies, here we train it
df_x = df[['lat','long']]                  #I need this part to do the prediction
prediction = clf.predict(df_x)             #clf.predict() returns an array
series_pred = pd.Series(prediction)        #now the array is a series
print(series_pred.shape)                   #RETURNS (2381,)
print(series_pred.isna().sum())            #RETURN 0
```

So far, so good. I have my 2381 predictions (I need only a few of them) **and there is no NaN value inside** (why would there be a NaN value in the predictions? **I just wanted to be sure**, as I don't understand my error)

Here I try to assign the predictions to my Dataframe:

```
#test_1
df.loc[df['my_colum'].isna(), 'my_colum'] = series_pred  #I assign the predictions using .loc()
#test_2
df['my_colum'] =  df['my_colum'].fillna(series_pred)     #Double check: I assign the predictions using .fillna()
print(df['my_colum'].shape)                      #RETURNS (2381,)
print(df['my_colum'].isna().sum())               #RETURN 6
```

As you can see, i**t didn't work: the missing values are still 6**. I randomly tried a slightly different approach:

```
#test_3
df[['my_colum']] =  df[['my_colum']].fillna(series_pred)     #Will it work?
print(df[['my_colum']].shape)                        #RETURNS (2381, 1)
print(df[['my_colum']].isna().sum())                 #RETURNS 6
```

Did not work. I decided to try one last thing: check the fillna result even before **assigning the results** to the original df:

```
In[42]:
print(df['my_colum'].fillna(series_pred).isna().sum())  #extreme test
Out[42]:
6
```

So... where is my **very very** stupid mistake? Thanks a lot

---

## EDIT 1

To show a little bit of the data,

```
In[1]:
df.head()
Out[1]:
      my_column      lat    long
 id                                                     
9df   Wil            51     5
4f3   Fabio          47     9
x32   Fabio          47     8   
z6f   Fabio          47     9  
a6f   Giovanni       47     7
```

Also, I've added info at the beginning of the question

Comment: hi Federico, could you post a sample of the data that you're working with? perhaps the output of the table as well.

Comment: Does the index (the row index) of `series_pred` match `df`?

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `df.loc[df['my_colum'].isna(), 'my_colum'] = series_pred[df['my_colum'].isna()]`? Also what's the difference between `df` and `df_x`?

Comment: @Dan I'm sure it does NOT match, but the items should be in the same order. About the difference between df and df_x, I will explain editing the question, give me 5 minutes

Comment: @Gorlomi I'm going to edit the question to answer you, give me 5 minutes

Comment: I would reset the index so that they do match... `series_pred.index = df.index`. I would guess something like `fillna` matches on the index and not on the location.

Comment: @Dan is right, when using a Series in `fillna`, it is index aligned. If you are sure of the size of your data, then `df.loc[df['my_colum'].isna(), 'my_colum'] = prediction` should do it, no need to create a Series

Comment: @Ben.T I did what you suggested, and I obtained a value error. **ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2381,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (6,)**. This make sense, because `df.loc[df['my_colum'].isna(), 'my_colum']` should actually be made just of 6 elements, while prediction is made of 2381 elements

Comment: Based on what Ben and Dan said, there should be only two solutions: using fillna() asking it to ignore the index (there is probably a way), or using loc() making the prediction only with the element I want to fill (this sounds more clean)

Comment: @FedericoDorato what I'm not sure about is why you do the prediction on your whole column while you actually just want the 6 rows with Nan. So once `clf` is trained, try `df.loc[df['my_colum'].isna(), 'my_colum'] = clf.predict(df.loc[df['my_colum'].isna(), ['lat','long']])`

Comment: @Ben.T I've done exactly what you said, just written differently. I predict every value just because for this kind of problem the computation is really quick, and I was needing some quick Maccheroni code. Please, post your answer ;)

Comment: @FedericoDorato you should accept your own answer, you did a good summary of what has been said in the comments, no need for me to add another answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ben.T or @Dan should post their own answers, they deserve to be accepted as the correct one.

Following their hints, I would say that there are two solutions:

### Solution 1 (Best): Use loc()

**The problem**

The problem with the current solution is that `df.loc[df['my_column'].isna(), 'my_column']` is expecting to receive X values, where X is the number of missing values. My variable `prediction` has actually both the prediction for the missing values and for the non missing values

**The solution**

```
pred_df = df[df['my_column'].isna()]        #For the prediction, use a Dataframe with only the missing values. Problem solved
df_x = pred_df[['lat','long']]
prediction = clf.predict(df_x)
df.loc[df['my_column'].isna(), 'my_column'] = prediction
```

### Solution 2: Use fillna()

**The problem**

The problem with the current solution is that `df['my_colum'].fillna(series_pred)` requires the indexes of my `df` to be the same of `series_pred`, which is impossible in this situation unless you have a simple index in your df, like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4...]

**The solution**

Resetting the index of the df at the very beginning of the code.

**Why is this not the best**

The cleanest way is to do the prediction only when you need it. This approach is easy to obtain with loc(), and I do not know how would you obtain it with fillna() because you would need to preserve the index through the classification

Edit: `series_pred.index = df['my_column'].isna().index` Thanks @Dan

Comment: It' not impossible, you just have to do `series_pred.index = df['my_column'].isna().index` and then `fillna` should be ok. But personally I would also stick with the slicing solution.